# How to create an instance in configuration manager

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

I'm working on a program to send multiple mails of users in a database from a single mail but I'm getting an error of

> object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the code for the connection to the DB.

```
            SqlCommand cmd = null;

            // Error occurs on the line below
            string connectionString = (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchedulingInterviewsConnectionString"].ConnectionString); 
            string queryString = @"SELECT Email FROM interview WHERE Email = Email";

            using (SqlConnection connection =
                       new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command =
                    new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString);
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: Either ConfigurationManager has not been set or there isn't a connection called "SchedulingInterviewsConnectionString" by the look of it. Check how that gets setup/populated.

Comment: Open the XML configuration file in your project with Notepad and check the connection string property.

Comment: The property is Scheduling InterviewsConnectionString  same as indicated on the code

Answer (score 0):

You can check as follow:
(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchedulingInterviewsConnectionString"] = null

You need add the ConnectionString of 'SchedulingInterviewsConnectionString'

Comment: Well, i tried. But that did not work. Thanks anyway.